# vertical line marker in dash progress bar

Tags: python, css, progress-bar, plotly-dash

I have been working on a python dash-app (dashboard) in which I want to show used budgets with a dash/bootstrap progress bar. I would like to mark 100% of the budget with a vertical line in the progress bar (see the images below). The bar itself should be fixed width and overflow should be shown with red color instead of green.

example 1:
[image: progress bar with line]

---

example 2:

[image]

I read the bootstrap and dash doc and tried to find a solution by myself, but since im only beginner in python and have no clue how to use CSS (in any other way than in dash)... i could need some help.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.